# Redirect C++ output stream to a file in VS 2010 without changing code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, stream

At the command prompt I might compile my program and then run as follows:

```
myprogram > output.txt
```

Is there a similar way of redirecting the output stream in VS2010? I want to debug/run my program within the IDE but have cout stream to a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just redirect the [stdout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x292kth.aspx) stream pointer.

```
freopen( "file.txt", "w", stdout );
```